# Is there a way of watching specific users or attributes with Google Directory API watch method

Tags: python, google-workspace, google-directory-api

I wanted to know if there is a way to create a watch channel for specific users or attributes ?

For example when I update the field organizational unit on a user i want to be notified when the action have been effectively performed without being obliged to get the user periodically.

I tried the use the query parameter when initializing the watch channel, in this case for what i understood of the documentation to watch users having a given name containing Jane, but it seems not to work because as I receive updates for all the domain.

```
users_service = service.users()
    channel_id = str(uuid4())
    watch_body = {
        "id": channel_id,
        "type": 'web_hook',
        "address": notifications_script,
        "params": {
            "ttl": watch_duration
        }
    }
    watch = users_service.watch(
        body=watch_body,
        event=event,
        customer=customer,
        query="givenName:Jane*"
    ).execute()
```

Can you please tell me if I am doing or understanding wrong or if what I entend to do is even possible.

Thank you very much in advance,
Raphaël

**PS** : I am using the google-api-python-client

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I was using the wrong API to fulfill my use case.

Use the reports API instead if you want to monitor activity on specif attributes or users of your domain.

Here is the corresponding documentation : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push.

Kind regards,
Raphaël